# Exporting as PDF attachment within Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, appery.io

I am using Appery.io as my mobile app developer, they do not provide such support so I thought I would ask here, how can I send a object on a page as an attachment upon exporting to Salesforce?

Please advise.

Answer (score -1):

I think you got it all wrong.You can't send anything to a page. It is not how client-server works through http. Page should have code to download data from server and show it on the page, regardless it is a salesforce or your own server.

You need to find salesforce apis to get your object from your DB, make an ajax call from your app's page to that api and parse response to a page.
In terms of PDF, you can download it or try to open directly on the page with Mozzila/PDF.js library